# Why do we use only [List, Map, Set] collections in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I've been learning Kotlin and I've faced with Collections API. Before Kotlin I'd been learning Java and I know that in Java there's a lot of different types of Collections API. For example, instead of general `List, Map, Queue, Set` we use `ArrayList, HashMap, LinkedList, LinkedMap` and etc. Though in Kotlin we only use general types like `Map, List, Set` but also we can use `HashMap` and etc. So, what's going on there? Can you help me to figure out?

Comment: In Kotlin we use all the collections that exist in Java. What is your question again?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari on the official website i saw where the docs wrote about `List, Map, Set` in Collections tab but not about something else

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While Kotlin's original and primary target is the JVM, there is a huge push by JetBrains to make it [multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html), and support JS and Native as well.

If you're using Kotlin on the JVM, the implementations of any collections you're using will still be the original JDK classes, e.g. `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.HashSet`. These are not reimplemented by the Kotlin standard library, which has some great benefits:

- These are well-tested implementations, which are maintained anyway.
- Using the exact same classes makes interop with Java a breeze, as you can pass them back and forth without having to perform conversions or mapping of any kind.

What Kotlin does do is introduce its own collection semantics *over* these existing implementations, in the form of the standard library interfaces such as `List`, `Map`, `MutableList`, `MutableMap` and so on. A small bit of [compiler magic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) makes it so that these interfaces are implemented by the existing JDK classes as well.

---

If you don't need a specific implementation of a certain type of collection, you can use your collections via these interfaces plus the respective factory methods of the standard library (`listOf`, `mapOf`, `mutableListOf`, `mutableMapOf`, etc.). This keeps your code more generic, and independent of the concrete underlying implementations. You don't know what specific class the standard library `mutableListOf` function will create for you, only that it will be an object that satisfies the contract of the `MutableList` interface.

You should basically use these interfaces by default in your code, especially in public API:

- In the case of function parameters, this lets clients provide the function with whatever implementation of the collection they wish to give you. If your function can operate on anything that's a `List`, you should ask for just that interface - no reason to require an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` specifically.
- If this is a return type, using these interfaces lets you change the specific implementation that you create internally in the future, without breaking client code. You can promise to just return a `MutableList` of things, and what implementation backs that list is not exposed to your clients.

If you look at all the [collection handling functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html#functions) of the Kotlin standard library, you'll see that on the surface, they almost exclusively operate on these interfaces. If you dig down deep enough, you'll find `ArrayList` instances being created, but this is not exposed to the client code, as it doesn't have to care about the concrete implementation most of the time.

---

Going back to the multiplatform point once more, if you write your code in a way such that it only relies on Kotlin standard library defined types, that code will be easily usable for non-JVM targets. If you reference `kotlin.MutableList` in your imports, that can immediately compile to JS code, because there's a Kotlin standard library implementation of that interface on each platform. Whether that maps to an existing class directly, wraps an existing class somehow, or is implemented for Kotlin from scratch, again, doesn't have to concern you. But if you refer to `java.util.TreeSet` in your code, that won't fly for the JS target, as the Java platform classes are not available there.

---

Can you still use classes such as `java.util.ArrayList` directly? Of course.

- If you don't see your code going multiplatform at some point, using Java collections directly is perfectly okay.
- If you need a specific implementation for a `List` or a `Set` for performance reasons, sometimes you'll have to use the Java classes directly.

Interestingly, in recent releases of Kotlin, these specific types of implementations (such as an array based list) are wrapped under standard library typealiases too, so that they're platform independent by default: see [`kotlin.collections.ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) or [`kotlin.collections.HashSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-set/index.html) for examples of this. These Kotlin-defined types will usually show up first in IntelliJ completion, so you'll find yourself being pushed towards using them wherever possible. Same thing goes for most exceptions, e.g. [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-illegal-argument-exception/index.html).

---

TL;DR: You can use either Kotlin collection types of Java types in Kotlin, but you should probably do the former whenever you can.